# How await in async is differ from normal execution in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, coroutine

[image: Async Program]

I have two function `kitchen()` and `waiter()`. In `waiter()` I have `awaited kitchen()` function. I know that if I await the function it will be waiting untill that particular function returns. Here, in waiter `await kitchen()` means `"Wait until the kitchen() function returns something"`. I have doubt that what is the use of this await with async compared to normal flow execution like below.

[image: Normal Program]

What is the difference between two programs?

Thanks in advance.

I have try to understand the difference between these two programs. But no clue found.

Comment: As this code is written, there is no difference. Both versions will run synchronously with a blocking sleep call in the middle. asyncio is beneficial when code needs to wait for something I/O-bound to complete. To see a difference, your first example should use `asyncio.sleep` instead of `time.sleep` and both examples should call `waiter` twice, with the first example using `asyncio.gather`.

Answer (score 0):

If you define an async function, say:

```
async def fun1():
    return 10
```

when you call the function:

```
>>> fun1()
<coroutine object fun1 at xxxxx>
```

As you can see, it returns a "coroutine". This coroutine needs to be executed by an "async event loop".

`await` is the keyword that means "execute this coroutine and give me its return value". But `await` is only legal inside another async function.

So if you do:

```
>>>await fun1()
```

You'll get a `SyntaxError`

So we need to write another async function, and use an async framework to execute that function:

```
async def call_this():
    print(fun1())
    print(await fun1())

import asyncio
asyncio.run(call_this())
```

You'll get:

```
<coroutine object fun1 at ...>
10
```

... plus a warning that there's a coroutine object that was never "awaited".

As you can see, the first invocation of `fun1()` without `await` *still* returns a coroutine object. The `await` keyword triggers the actual execution of the coroutine object, in this case the function `fun1()`, and returns the function's return value.

So, what is the difference?

The difference is that `async` allows "asynchronous" execution of tasks. It's not parallel processing; rather, at certain points where the task needs to wait on an external resource (e.g., waiting for download of a file to finish) it can 'yield' execution to other tasks.

"asynchronous", in other words, is "cooperative multitasking": Every task must explicitly yield at certain points to allow other tasks to run. The `await` keyword is also a signal that at this point the task will have to wait a response from another coroutine, so the async event loop can 'switch' to doing other tasks.

Imagine asynchronous as a restaurant with a single waiter. Rather that getting a table's order, sending the order to the kitchen, and wait until the order is complete, the waiter just hands over the order to the kitchen and proceeds to take the order from other tables, while regularly checking the kitchen window for finished orders.

So rather than:

- Grab order #1, bring to kitchen, wait until finished, bring to table
- Grab order #2, bring to kitchen, wait until finished, bring to table
- Grab order #3, bring to kitchen, wait until finished, bring to table

The waiter will do:

- Grab order #1, bring to kitchen, can this be instantly done? No? Okay, I'll leave you to work on this...
- Grab order #2, bring to kitchen, can this be instantly done? No? Okay, I'll leave you to work on this...
- By the way, is order #1 finished? No? Okay, I'll leave you to work on this...
- Grab order #3, bring to kitchen, can this be instantly done? No? Okay, I'll leave you to work on this...
- By the way, is order #1 finished? No? Okay, I'll leave you to work on this...
- By the way, is order #2 finished? Yes? Cool, I'll bring the order back to the table
- Grab order #4 ... and so on ...