network_config_edit_view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned an unawaited coroutine. You may need to add an 'await' into your view
I am working in a django webpage, and I was asked to do an async check for the netplan in the server the page is hosted after doing modifications, I have this view:
async def network_config_edit_view(request):
path = '/etc/netplan/00-network.yaml'
backup_path = '/etc/netplan/00-network.yaml.backup'

www_data_uid = 33
www_data_gid = 33

try:
    if await sync_to_async(os.path.exists, thread_sensitive=True)(backup_path):
        await sync_to_async(os.remove, thread_sensitive=True)(backup_path)
    await sync_to_async(shutil.copy, thread_sensitive=True)(path, backup_path)
    print(f"Backup of the original file created at {backup_path}.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error creating backup file: {e}")

config_data = await sync_to_async(read_network_config, thread_sensitive=True)(path)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = NetworkConfigForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
        data_to_save = {
            'ipv4_addresses': [cleaned_data.get('ipv4_address')] if cleaned_data.get('ipv4_address') else [],
            'ipv6_addresses': [cleaned_data.get('ipv6_address')] if cleaned_data.get('ipv6_address') else [],
            'ipv4_gateway': cleaned_data.get('ipv4_gateway', ''),
            'ipv6_gateway': cleaned_data.get('ipv6_gateway', ''),
            'dns_addresses': [addr.strip() for addr in cleaned_data.get('ipv4_dns', '').split(',') if addr.strip()] +
                             [addr.strip() for addr in cleaned_data.get('ipv6_dns', '').split(',') if addr.strip()]
        }
        try:
            await sync_to_async(save_to_yaml, thread_sensitive=True)(data_to_save, file_path=path)
            await sync_to_async(os.chown, thread_sensitive=True)(path, www_data_uid, www_data_gid)
            await sync_to_async(os.chmod, thread_sensitive=True)(path, 0o664)
            print("YAML file has been saved.")
            messages.success(request, "The new configuration has been saved successfully.")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error saving YAML file: {e}")
            messages.error(request, f"Error saving YAML file: {e}")
            context = {
                'form': form,
                **admin.site.each_context(request),
                'error': f"Error saving YAML file: {e}",
            }
            html = render_to_string('admin/network_config_edit.html', context)
            return HttpResponse(html)

        
        if await apply_netplan():
            
            if await check_network_status():
                
                await sync_to_async(restart_services, thread_sensitive=True)()
                messages.success(request, "Services restarted successfully.")
            else:
                messages.error(request, "Network check failed after applying netplan.")
                context = {
                    'form': form,
                    **admin.site.each_context(request),
                    'error': "Network check failed after applying netplan.",
                }
                html = render_to_string('admin/network_config_edit.html', context)
                return HttpResponse(html)
        else:
            messages.error(request, "Failed to apply netplan.")
            context = {
                'form': form,
                **admin.site.each_context(request),
                'error': "Failed to apply netplan.",
            }
            html = render_to_string('admin/network_config_edit.html', context)
            return HttpResponse(html)

else:
    form = NetworkConfigForm(initial=config_data)

context = {
    'form': form,
    **admin.site.each_context(request),
}
html = render_to_string('admin/network_config_edit.html', context)
return HttpResponse(html)

and these functions:
async def apply_netplan():
process = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell('sudo netplan apply', stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)

stdout, stderr = await process.communicate()

if process.returncode == 0 :
    print("Netplan applied successfully.")
    return True
else:
    print(f"Netplan apply failed: {stderr.decode()}")
    return False

async def check_network_status():
for _ in range(10):
    result = await asyncio.create_subprocess_shell(
            'ping -c 1 8.8.8.8',
            stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    stdout, stderr = await result.communicate()

    if result.returncode == 0:
        print("Network is up.")
        return True
    await asyncio.sleep(5)
return False


def restart_services():
try:
    result = subprocess.run(['systemctl', 'restart', 'gunicorn'], capture_output=True, text=True, check=True)
    print("Gunicorn service started successfully.")
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(f"Error starting Gunicorn service: {e.stderr}")
    raise e

I have no clue what might be wrong here, do you guys have any suggestion?
The main idea is a user can make modifications in the netplan by editing the yaml file through the page, it saves the new conf and applies netplan apply and restarts gunicorn, but when I go into the editing page, I get the error in the title.

What's happening is summarized here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74221048/how-await-in-async-is-differ-from-normal-execution-in-python

Otherwise Django has some async support: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/async/
